# wordpress count image attachments

Tags: wordpress, count, attachment

I'm looking for some help, for some reason this code isn't working when trying to display total image attachments on the main `index.php` page.

```
// Get all the attachments
$attachments = get_posts ( array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
'post_status' => 'inherit',
) );

// Count all the attachments
$total = count( $attachments );
```

The problem is, the loop is in the main `index.php` page, but it's calling a `post.php` template so I have placed this code there instead (I'm assuming that's still in the loop?) I am then calling `$total` just below it where I want to show "View all # images".

Any ideas why this is just displaying the number as 0 even though I have added an image gallery to the post using the basic Wordpress gallery media library?

Thanks

Comment: If you add `print_r($attachments);` is there anything printed to the page?

Comment: It actually seemed to have worked in the end. It seemed to be a problem with the images we were using to try and count. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The attachment count only increases if it's attached to a post. You can force the count by adding this:

`$wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback = '_update_generic_term_count';`

in a function in your functions.php something like this:

```
function change_category_arg() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    if ( ! taxonomy_exists('category') )
        return false;

    $wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback = '_update_generic_term_count';

}
add_action( 'init', 'change_category_arg' );
```

Explanation:

> This is significant in the case of attachments. Because an attachment
>   is a type of post, the default _update_post_term_count() will be used.
>   However, this may be undesirable, because this will only count
>   attachments that are actually attached to another post (like when you
>   insert an image into a post). This means that attachments that you
>   simply upload to WordPress using the Media Library, but do not
>   actually attach to another post will not be counted. If your intention
>   behind associating a taxonomy with attachments was to leverage the
>   Media Library as a sort of Document Management solution, you are
>   probably more interested in the counts of unattached Media items, than
>   in those attached to posts. In this case, you should force the use of
>   _update_generic_term_count() by setting '_update_generic_term_count' as the value for update_count_callback.

from [Wordpress Codex on register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)